# SQL query to reduce number of rows using grouping values in lesser number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, qsqlquery

I have set of data which looks like below

[image: Given Data]

I want to reduce the rows in it. If possible to reduce up to single row then it would be considered as best case.

Final data set should something like this
[image: Expected data]

I tried Min and Max functions in SQL. But I don't want to loose any data. Just want to fill blank cells so that readability of report.

If anyone need sample data then you may use below query

```
select * from
(
SELECT 9999 as primary_key ,1 AS column_1, 2 as column_2, NULL  as column_3, NULL as column_4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 9999, NULL, NULL, 3, 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 9999, 5, 6, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
)
```

Comment: I have removed the tag spam here, please only tag the actual product you are using.

Comment:  Please do not link to [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data.

Comment: There could be more than 3 records for each key? Possible a record could have data in every field? I doubt that output is possible with SQL alone. Can concatenate the multiple values under each column to a CSV string for each key. Method depends on RDBMS used. Add appropriate tag.

Comment: Yes @June7, It is possible to have more than 3 records for each kay. Yes. It's possible for record to have data in every field.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest working the current data into an "unpivoted state" that excludes NULL values and whilst doing this add a row number into the mix. Then once that is available then re-pivot that interim result into the wanted final format using both the primary_key and the row number:

```
WITH UNPIV AS (
    SELECT PRIMARY_KEY, 'column_1' AS COLUMN_NAME, column_1 AS COLUMN_VALUE
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PRIMARY_KEY ORDER BY column_1) AS RN
    FROM your_table
    WHERE column_1 IS NOT NULL
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT PRIMARY_KEY, 'column_2' AS COLUMN_NAME, column_2 AS COLUMN_VALUE
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PRIMARY_KEY ORDER BY column_2) AS RN
    FROM your_table
    WHERE column_2 IS NOT NULL
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT PRIMARY_KEY, 'column_3' AS COLUMN_NAME, column_3 AS COLUMN_VALUE
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PRIMARY_KEY ORDER BY column_3) AS RN
    FROM your_table
    WHERE column_3 IS NOT NULL
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT PRIMARY_KEY, 'column_4' AS COLUMN_NAME, column_4 AS COLUMN_VALUE
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PRIMARY_KEY ORDER BY column_4) AS RN
    FROM your_table
    WHERE column_4 IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT PRIMARY_KEY, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'column_1' THEN COLUMN_VALUE END) AS COLUMN_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'column_2' THEN COLUMN_VALUE END) AS COLUMN_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'column_3' THEN COLUMN_VALUE END) AS COLUMN_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'column_4' THEN COLUMN_VALUE END) AS COLUMN_4
FROM UNPIV
GROUP BY PRIMARY_KEY, RN
ORDER BY PRIMARY_KEY, RN
```

| PRIMARY_KEY | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 | COLUMN_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9999 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 9999 | 5 | 6 | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_ymWTpgo)

Note the arrangement of values into these rows is determined by the row_number() calculation. So there is no guarantee that values will re-align into the same rows that they originated from.